# Attribute access works in print statement but raises AttributeError about NoneType in while loop

Tags: python

I'm getting an "**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute**" error while using a `while` loop on some object.

I'm trying to implement a linked list in Python.
I'd used `print` for debugging, and it output a value as expected (not `None`), but while using this instance in a loop I got an error.

The `delete` function:

```py
    def delete(self , value):
        current = self.head
        #for debugging proposes 
        print("the next value is: "+str(current.next.value))
        #got an error here
        while current.next:
            if current.next.value == value:
                current.next = current.next.next
            current = current.next
```

I expect the loop to work normally, because there was output from `print()`, however I got this output:

```
the next value is: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    ll.delete(3)
  File "/home/xxx/Desktop/pc/LinkedList.py", line 6, in delete
    while (current.next):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you can tell that `current` is *not* `None` at the moment the `print` statement is executed, because it does not raise an exception...
But it clearly is `None` when the `while current.next:` line runs.

Your problem seems to be that you think execution proceeds like this:

> `print` then `while` then other-stuff.

...which ignores the loop.
It's more like:

> `print` then `while` then change-things then `while` then change-things then `while`-oops-KABOOM!

For one example, when you delete the last node of your linked list, you change two things:

1. `current.next` is rebound to whatever the deleted node's `next` pointed to, which for the last node is usually `None`.
2. `current` is rebound to that same value.

Then your `while` statement tests `current.next`, which is really `None.next`, which doesn't exist.

You could solve this by adding extra checks to the body of your `while` loop, but I'd replace the condition itself with `while current is not None:` instead.
It would require re-writing your loop's body, but it would solve this problem, and it would also prevent a similar crash if anyone attempts to `delete` from an empty linked list.

Comment: I don't get it to be honest, according to this documentation https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html. None is considered as a false value which means that the loop shouldn't be executed, is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: @AbdullahKhalid: Yes, `None` is considered false, but your `while` condition is not testing `None` in the situations I described.  It is testing `current.next` which is _not_ `None` --- it is `None.next`, which does not exist.  To break it down into smaller steps: evaluating the truth value of `current.next` requires multiple steps: figure out what `current` points to, then look up that object's `next` attribute and evaluate its "truthiness"...  But `current` evaluates to `None`, and `None` doesn't _have_ a `next` attribute... which is exactly what the `AttributeError` message says.

Comment: @AbdullahKhalid: Consider printing the value of `current` at the end of the `while` loop, immediately after it's assigned.  That will let you see its value immediately before the next test of the `while` condition.

Answer (score 2):

make sure `current` variable is not `null` or `NoneType` before calling its attributes. check if your variable is not null. try this:

```
def delete(self , value):
        current = self.head
        if not current is None:
            #for debugging proposes 
            print("the next value is: "+str(current.next.value))
            #got an error here
            while current.next:
                if current.next.value == value:
                    current.next = current.next.next
                current = current.next
```

read more about `AttributeError` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/dont-understand-what-this-attributeerror-means).

Comment: the same error, can I access an  attribute if the instance is none?

Comment: @AbdullahKhalid no you can't